# Seeking shapefile for Australia and New Zealand?

Tags: data, australia, new-zealand

I was trying to find a shapefile which has Australia and New Zealand together (states) so that I could convert to jVectorMap for ANZ.

Where I can find it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Natural Earth website](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/) is pretty good for freely available Geographic data, including Country boundaries.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the data for Australia straight from their government's website: http://data.daff.gov.au/anrdl/metadata_files/pa_nsaasr9nnd_02211a04.xml

Here is the data for New Zealand from their government's data portal:
http://www.stats.govt.nz/browse_for_stats/people_and_communities/Geographic-areas/digital-boundary-files.aspx

From here you can merge the two shapefiles in QGIS or ArcMap or whatever GIS software you are using.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use OpenStreetMap data. Global land and water polygons are freely available from http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/land-polygons, a service offered by Jochen Topf. In contrast to the above mentioned Natural Earth dataset OpenStreetMap data is much more detailed and therefore requires more disk space.

Answer (score 2):

the [Global Administrative Districts](http://www.gadm.org/country) has shapefiles (and geopackages, kmz, etc) for all countries.  The most recent release was in May 2018 and this is a high quality, comprehensive, one-stop shop for political boundaries.

The [U.S. State Department GeoNode](http://geonode.state.gov/) also maintains international boundaries in GIS format,

Answer (score 0):

You can find Shapefile of Australia at https://www.igismap.com/australia-shapefile-download/?utm_source=Gisexchange&utm_medium=Ausshp&utm_campaign=J
Download free polygon administrative Shapefile of Australia. It covers local Australian government borders.